# USB wifi not working

Tags: wifi, usb, intel, realtek

I've connected AWUS036H usb wifi dongle.
On the notebook I already have an internal wifi card using the iwlwifi driver (intel).
This uses the rl2800usb and shows as (disabled) when viewing the list of available network cards.
It seems like it tries to start working but then is killed by something. This can be seen in the wifi area, as you can see a new wifi pops up and then disappears and so on.
Also, with the iwconfig, the card comes up and down. Meaning that by continually executing the iwconfig command, the card can be seen as wlan0, then there is no card, then it can be seen as wlp0s20ul, then nothing again, wlan0 and so on...
What can be the cause? What is "killing" it?

*lsusb*

```
Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

Comment: `dmesg` might provide relevant information.

Comment: I can see a: ieee80211 phyXX: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0xffffffff]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a bad USB cable...